# case class product iterator to make string

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to make a string representation of case class

```
 case class Person(s:Student)
  case class Student(name:String,value:String){
    def toMyString(flag:Boolean):String= if(flag)s"${name} =${value}" else s"Hello${name}+${value}"
  }

  Person(Student("abc","def")).productIterator
```

I want to call `toMyString` from `productIterator`.

My actual use case has many elements in case class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for generating the `String` for the element:

1.Create a `trait` for `elements` that need to implement `toMyString` and the elements that need to generate string extends from it, and implement it, like:

```
  trait MyString {
    def toMyString(flag: Boolean): String
  }
  case class Student(name: String, value: String) extends MyString{
    def toMyString(flag: Boolean): String = if (flag) s"${name} =${value}" else s"Hello${name}+${value}"
  }
  val result: List[String] = Person(Student("abc","def")).productIterator.collect{
   case x: MyString => x.toMyString(true)
  }
```

2. Use the `reflection` for this by get `toMyString` method by **method name**, this is a tricky way and not type safe, should think more about this, like:

```
  val student = Student("abc", "def")
  val res: Iterator[String] = Person(student).productIterator.map(i => {
    val method = i.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.filter(i => i.getName.equals("toMyString")).headOption
    method match {
      case Some(m) =>
        m.invoke(i, true.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
      case None =>
        null
 }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just ask each iterator element if it is the target type.

```
Person(Student("abc","def")).productIterator.collect{
  case x:Student => x.toMyString(true)
}
// res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator (String: "abc=def")
```

Answer (score 1):

We need `Iterator[Student]` instead of `Iterator[Any]`

```
Person(Student("abc","def")).productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Student]]
```